# Visual Studio 2005 error with Unicode

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset

```
    Dim findTheseVals(1) As Object
    ' Set the values of the keys to find.
    Dim myDAgn As New SqlDataAdapter

    findTheseVals(0) = pDivisionno
    findTheseVals(1) = pGNe

    sqlCon.Open()

    Dim myDSGN As New DataSet
    myDAgn.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Villages", sqlCon)
    myDAgn.Fill(myDSGN, "Villages")

    myPrimaryKey(0) = myDSGN.Tables("Villages").Columns("DivisionNo")
    myPrimaryKey(1) = myDSGN.Tables("Villages").Columns("VillageSin")

    myDSGN.Tables("Villages").PrimaryKey = myPrimaryKey

    Dim myRow As DataRow

    myRow = myDSGN.Tables("Villages").Rows.Find(findTheseVals)


    If Not (myRow Is Nothing) Then
        isExistsVi = True
        VIid = myRow.Item("VillageID")
    Else
        isExistsVi = False
    End If
    sqlCon.Close()
```

pGNe is Parameter
VillageSin is a Column and contain UNICODE Data
When compile following error erised
"These Columns dont' Currently have unique values"

How can search unicode data from  Dataset 
How to correct above c

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this line

`myDSGN.Tables("Villages").PrimaryKey = myPrimaryKey`

is the one with the error "These Columns dont' Currently have unique values" because your data is running afoul of the unique requirement on primary keys.

All this means is that you can't use `Find`. This has nothing to do with SQL Server or Unicode data.

instead  get rid of this line `myDSGN.Tables("Villages").PrimaryKey = myPrimaryKey` and use [.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead